# typo3: what is the difference between ux_tx_extension_pi1 and tx_extension_pi1?

Tags: typo3

I am checking one extension file, and use `var_dump(get_class($pObj));` to output the class name, it shows `ux_tx_dapost_pi1`, my question is: what is the difference between  `ux_tx_dapost_pi1` and `tx_dapost_pi1`, I know `“ux” is a prefix meaning “user-extension”`, but how could I find out the detailed info about the difference between `ux_tx_dapost_pi1` and `tx_dapost_pi1`? such as: they have different methods?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any class without the "ux" prefix? - If not, the difference is just about the naming. There are no restrictive naming conventions in TYPO3, so you are almost free to use any name with some exceptions.

Comment: I would like to add that "usually" this is a hint that this is just an [`XCLASS`](http://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS), so some more methods may be in the base class. You can see all the extended classes in the TYPO3 backend in admin tools=>configuration and then in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']` where `TYPO3_MODE` may be `FE` or `BE`.